# What happens with the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$ when $|z|=1, z$ a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

The sum converges for all $z$ such that $|z|<1$ and diverges if $|z|>1$, but what happens if $|z|=1$?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=1$ the series is well known to be divergent.
If $|z|=1$ but $z\neq 1$ the series is semi-convergent thanks to dirichlet criterion : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: How do you prove that $|\sum_{n=1}^{N}{z^n}|<M$ for all N?

Comment: Since $z\not=1$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^N z^n=\dfrac{z^{n+1}-z}{1-z}$.

Comment: Write $z=e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in\mathbb{R}\setminus 2\pi\mathbb{N}$, then your sum is $\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\theta}=e^{i(N+1)\theta/2}\sin(N\theta/2)/\sin(\theta/2)$, which is clearly bounded.